# Owl Carousel Efficient DOM Management

Tags: javascript, dom, owl-carousel

I am using Owl carousel plugin in my mobile app(iOS & Android) in Phonegap and i can have more than 100 or can be thousands of owl items or slides. 
When the DOM gets bigger, this may cause crash of the app because of memory issue.

What I want to achieve is to remove the "not" visible div(the owl item) when the user is sliding.

This is a sample DOM generated after initializing OwlCarousel :

```
<div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 8164px; left: 0px; display: block; -webkit-transition: all 0ms ease; transition: all 0ms ease; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 314px;">
    <div class="item dodgerBlue">
        <h1>Start</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 314px;">
    <div class="item dodgerBlue">
        <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 314px;">
    <div class="item dodgerBlue">
        <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 314px;">
    <div class="item dodgerBlue">
        <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 314px;">
    <div class="item dodgerBlue">
        <h1>4</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 314px;">
    <div class="item dodgerBlue">
        <h1>5</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 314px;">
    <div class="item dodgerBlue">
        <h1>6</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 314px;">
    <div class="item dodgerBlue">
        <h1>7</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 314px;">
    <div class="item dodgerBlue">
        <h1>8</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 314px;">
    <div class="item dodgerBlue">
        <h1>9</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 314px;">
    <div class="item dodgerBlue">
        <h1>10</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 314px;">
    <div class="item dodgerBlue">
        <h1>11</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 314px;">
    <div class="item dodgerBlue">
        <h1>12</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the number of items gets bigger, this may cause memory issue and causes the crash of the app. I tried this in my iOS app but it crashes before it can display the OWL Carousel.

What i want to achieve is to remove the elements not currently visible from the DOM and add them later when they are near with the current visible element.

Lets say for example the current visible item is the item number 7, the item 5,6,7,8,9 should only be in the DOM and rest is removed. When the user swipes from item 7 to item 8, the item 6,7,8,9,10 should now be in the DOM.

I havent tried coding so far except for initializing the owl carousel.

I am not sure if my approach will be the best but i am asking for opinion of others before i proceed.

Whats the best way on handling this kind of scenario for Owl Carousel?

NOTE :

TurnJS (http://www.turnjs.com) used this kind of approach too. Don't know if that helps.

Hoping for any suggestions and opinions.

Comment: There's an example of lazy loading here: http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/lazyLoad.html

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex this is not what i want, this still loads all the item(div) in the DOM. The images are loaded when it gets visible but their container (item div) is in the DOM already

Comment: The tag wiki for [tag:owl] says "The Web Ontology Language (OWL) is a vocabulary for creating schemas (ontologies), i.e. definitions of classes, properties and the relationships between them."  This is not about OWL and should not be tagged with [tag:owl].  It should be tagged with [tag:owl-carousel].  I've fixed it this time, but please be sure to look at the tag descriptions in the future. :)

Comment: any solution????